# Get List of PropertyNames passed in Model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm trying to get all of the values from the value provider associated with the model name prefix.

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    if (values.Length == 0)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I know I could re-parse the query string but I figured the Model Binder would have already parse the rest of the values so why not grab them through there. 
Once I have the property key how can I get there values?

Comment: do you need to get all available keys that could be used `bindingContextValueProvider.GetValue`? Or you need to get value(s) held in  `values`? For the second case, there are `values.Values` and `values.FirstValue` properties.

Comment: @set that's what I would have assumed it would be but neither work.